# Does $3 \times\ 1$ matrix A map $A:\Bbb R^1\to \Bbb R^1$ or $A:\Bbb R^1\to \Bbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For example, if you multiply it with any $1 \times\ 1$ vector, you'd get a line which lives in $R^3$ but the resulting area would be a subspace of $R^3$. Do we still have to say $A:\Bbb R^1\to \Bbb R^3$ or $A:\Bbb R^1\to \Bbb R^1$ because it's just 1 dimensional line?

Comment: The codomain of a function is not the image of the domain under the function. So here, $A: \mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map (a.k.a. transformation) has three components:

- *domain* $\mathbb{R}\;\leftarrow\;$ inputs live here
- *codomain* $\mathbb{R}^3\;\leftarrow\;$ outputs land here
- *rule* $T\;\leftarrow\;$ how inputs become outputs

which gives the familiar notation $T:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Your transformation $T$ is completely described by the matrix $A$, which is a list/array of numbers.

Your intuition is correct that the *image* of $T$ (a.k.a. the *range* of $T$) is a line in $3$-space. But it's only that: a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the span of the $3$-vector (equivalently, the $3 \times 1$ matrix):
$$
\operatorname{Im} T := \{ T(x) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
The bottom line is: the codomain of map $T$ is the type of outputs; whereas, the image of $T$ consists of the *actual* outputs. When $T$ is a *linear* transformation, the image is a *linear* subspace.